# Validation is not happening when enter key is pressed instead of clicking button

Tags: javascript, reactjs, validation

I have a login form when I click on the button the validation works fine but when I press the enter key the validation doesn't work and I redirect to the wrong page. I have the below function where the `signin` function is present

```
renderSignIn() {
    const {
        state,
        onSignInAttempt,
        onSignInSuccess,
        onFormError,
        handleForgotPassword,
        handleCreateAccount
    } = this.props;

    return (
        <>
            <Form
              key="sign-in"
              onSubmit={ onSignInAttempt }
              onSubmitSuccess={ onSignInSuccess }
              onSubmitError={ onFormError }
            >
                <Field
                  type="text"
                  label={ __('Email') }
                  id="email"
                  name="email"
                  validation={ ['notEmpty', 'email'] }
                  placeholder={'Enter your email address'}
                />
                <Field
                  type="password"
                  label={ __('Password') }
                  id="password"
                  name="password"
                  validation={ ['notEmpty', 'password'] }
                  placeholder={'Enter password'}
                />
                <button
                  block="Button"
                  mods={ { likeLink: true } }
                  onClick={ handleForgotPassword }
                >
                    { __('Forgot password?') }
                </button>
                <div block="MyAccountOverlay" elem="Buttons">
                    <button block="Button">{ __('Sign in') }</button>
                </div>
                <div block="MyAccountOverlay" elem="SignInConditions">
                <p block="SignInTerms">By Signing In, you agree to <a href="">Terms of use</a> and<a href="">Privacy Notice.</a></p>  
                </div>
                
            </Form>
            <article block="MyAccountOverlay" elem="Additional" mods={ { state } }>
                <section>
                    <h4 id="forgot-password-label">{ __('New here?') }</h4>
                    <button
                      block="Button"
                      onClick={ handleCreateAccount }
                    >
                        { __('Create an account') }
                    </button>
                </section>
            </article>
        </>
    );
}
}
```

I have this function `hanldeForgotPassword()` below

```
handleForgotPassword(e) {
    const { setHeaderState } = this.props;
    e.preventDefault();
    e.nativeEvent.stopImmediatePropagation();
    this.setState({ state: STATE_FORGOT_PASSWORD });
    setHeaderState({ name: CUSTOMER_ACCOUNT, title: 'Forgot password' });
}
```

How do I solve it and I have tried adding `div` instead of `button` but it doesn't work

Comment: Seems all your buttons are submit buttons (default is `type="submit"`) and I suspect pressing the enter key while focused anywhere in the form submits it. Can you provide a more accurate repro for what you are doing to cause the issue?

Comment: do you have any redirects  logic in your js ?

Comment: @Toxy I dont have any redirects in my js

Comment: check if page have any other form  or input type='submit' in that page not the componenet whole page .

Comment: @Toxy there are other two functions in the same component which has `<button block="Button" type="submit"> {__('Send Reset Link')} </button>

Answer (score 1):

As all of your html is right so try adding : `onKeyPress="return handleChange(event)"` function to all your input.

```
handleChange = (event) => {
        event.preventDefault();
        var keyCode = event.keyCode || event.which;
        if (keyCode == '13'){
            console.log('enter pressed');
            return false;
        }
    }
```

Source : https://stackoverflow.com/a/38575630/11492378